# VPN excluding certain applications?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I currently have some VPN configs running, they work well. UDP. They run from openvpn config files.

However I'm wondering if I can somehow fairly easily set one up to that same kind of vpn but to exclude, say, a specific browser application so that I could that browser to bypass the vpn?

for example: chromium on vpn (if vpn is active) and firefox bypassing the vpn

Comment: See [Route the traffic over specific interface for a process in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but requires some knowledge. When you establish VPN connection, it basically changes your default gateway and all apps go through it. One way to overcome this is to have for example container (docker or LXD) which contains proxy and uses your original gateway and then you set firefox to use that proxy. Not trivial, but possible.

Comment: ok thanks I guess too much trouble than it's worth for me

Answer (score 2):

There's free and open source [**Qomui**](https://github.com/corrad1nho/qomui) app which has an option to [bypass VPN tunnel](https://github.com/corrad1nho/qomui#bypass) based on approach from [answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/761780/182465).

[image]

You can install it from here: https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Acorrad1nho&package=qomui
I suggest using version 0.8.2 because latest (0.8.3) introduced DNS leak.